# Keil, microvision 5, library for drivers include error

Tags: dll, stm32, keil

I am trying to add STM32L4xx_HAL drivers (.c sources) to the path but it keeps on saying the drivers are not found.

I have added the path into the **"project options - C/C++ tab"** section.
and **I have checked clearly that these sources exist** in these files.

Any ideas? please help

Here are some captured configuration
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIodA.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rotXf.png

Answer (score 1):

That is the include paths. You have to add the C files to the project manager on the left hand side.

Comment: I have already added the sources in the project.
But the problem is that in the left side, within the Drivers folder, 
I see the "exclamation mark !" icon next to all the sources (ex. stm32l4xx_hal.c) 

Do I need to add these in the project file..? I think this should be included in the path... so as shown in the images I added, I DID add the path.. but it says it can't find the file. So I checked to see if the files weren't there. But they were there and they open well in a separate window....

Answer (score 0):

In include path , Only include the header files. Also add the source files to your project, Source files will be built along with your application files.

Comment: I have already added the sources in the project. But the problem is that in the left side, within the Drivers folder, I see the "exclamation mark !" icon next to all the sources (ex. stm32l4xx_hal.c) Do I need to add these in the project file..? I think this should be included in the path... so as shown in the images I added, I DID add the path.. but it says it can't find the file. So I checked to see if the files weren't there. But they were there and they open well in a separate window...

Comment: Yes, You need to add everything in project files. Project files + driver source files will be the complete project. Do add all the headers, hal files and all dependencies into your project.

Comment: Another thing you can do is .. download the compele HAL library and look for examples and see what files and headers they included in the path and you follow the same. Sometimes we tend to overlook things assuming this is part of the project , but actually they are not.